# Sphinx is matching beginning of words?

Tags: sphinx

I thought a sphinx search only matched whole works by default. In searching for various acronyms I seem to match beginnings as well.  For instance 'prov' will match 'provide' not 'improve'. I only want it in fact to match " prov ". Is there some setting I need to change to make it 'Word' only?

Index Settings:

```
 wordforms = /home/indexer/wordform.txt
 stopwords  = /home/indexer/stopwords.txt
 stopword_step = 0
 morphology = stem_en
 index_sp=1
 html_strip = 1
 min_word_len = 1
 min_infix_len = 1
```

Follow-up: I min_infix_len = 0 (and rotated index) to no avail.

Comment: I dont think it effects your specific example, but remember you have stemming as well, which can mean prefixes match too (ie both have the same stem).

Comment: Also are you definitly not adding * to the query - or have expand_keywords?

Comment: @barryhunter Yes I just searched for (in this case) EAD e.g. select description from idx_TEST WHERE (MATCH('@(description ) "EAD"'))  as far as I know it should not match "bla bla eading". But I guess the stemming would in fact do that. So far in fact not su impressed with stemming it misses many stems I'd expect and adds ones I'd not expect so perhaps the best idea is to turn it off and build my own library. I will ask that separately thank you.